# PowerShell :: Regex Search in a File

Tags: regex, powershell, file

Its my first day with PowerShell and i am trying to search no of occurrence of a REGEX pattern in a file and set this count into a variable.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$notMatchingLines = Get-Content "pathToYourFile" | Select-String "YourRegex" -NotMatch
```

If you want to know the number of lines not matching to your regex you can do:

```
$notMatchtingLines.Count
```

Practical example, return all lines from my vimrc not containing the word "set":

```
>$linesNotContaingSet = Get-Content .\_vimrc | Select-String "set" -NotMatch
>$LinesNotContaingSet.GetType()

 IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
 -------- -------- ----                                     --------
 True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

The result is an array:

```
 > $LinesNotContaingSet[0]
 call plug#begin()
```

The number of lines not matching:

```
 > $LinesNotContaingSet.Count
```

If you want to know what else you can do with the returned object(s), use `Get-Member` (alias =`gm`):

```
> $LinesNotContaingSet | gm


TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method     type GetType()
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext  Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

To get deeper into Powershell checkout [MVA PowerShell Jumpstart](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276) videos.

Hope that helps

Comment: The way I am reading this, the `no` in `search no of occurrence of a REGEX pattern in a file` stands for **number of occurrences**, just saying

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Presuming with no you mean number:

for file content using Select-String, Measure-Object

```
$Count = (Select-String -Pattern 'pattern' -Path 'x:\path\file.txt'|Measure-Object).Count
```

For a variable and using .net

```
$Count = [regex]::matches($Content,'pattern').count
```

One hint here Select-String is by default case insensitive,
the dot net method not. You could prepend the pattern with `(?i)` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Juste do it:

```
Select-String -Path "PathFile" -Pattern "YourRegex" -NotMatch
```